# Problema con filtro en rango de fechas sql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, oracle-sqldeveloper

Hola buenas tardes tengo un problema con una de mis consultas SQL, estoy trabajando en un servidor remoto que automatiza el envío de información de las consultas, lo que necesito es que la consulta filtre solo los datos que se procesan antes o justo a  las 4:00PM mi consulta es la siguiente:

```
DECLARE @FromDate DATETIME, @ToDate DATETIME

SET @FromDate =  DATEADD (dd,-2,GETDATE())

SET @ToDate = DATEADD   (dd,+1,GETDATE())

select 
    RecvDate,
    DocType BatchType, 
    pbatch BatchName, 
    InvTime BatchCreationTime,
    Invtime ScanTime,
    InvTime SeparationTime,
    Imageexport QAOutTime,
    Imageexport ExportTime, 
    FTPTime, 
    format(sum(doccount),'N0') TotalDocs,
    DATEDIFF(hour,imageexport,ftptime) TAT_Hours, 
    case 
        when cast(ftptime as date) = cast(InvTime as date) 
        then 'Passed' 
        else 'Failed'

    end Compliance 
    FROM View_CNAWFStatus v  
    where cast(RecvDate as date) 
    between @FromDate and @ToDate 
    and FTPTime is not null and DocType

    in ( select DocumentType from DocumentType) 
    and InvTime <= '12/30/2023 4:00 PM'

group by RecvDate, DocType, pbatch, imageexport, invtime, ftptime order by RecvDate, DocType, pbatch, imageexport, invtime, ftptime;
```

El valor que necesito que filtre es Invtime, para lo cual he probado

```
Invtime <= '12/30/2023 4:00 PM'
```

debo aclarar que el formato de fecha que he puesto para la comparación es el adecuado ya que así muestra los resultados de fecha y hora, sin embargo no respeta está comparación y muestra resultados mayores a la fecha y hora.

Alguna idea de cómo puedo arreglar este problema?

Comment: Parece haber ignorado por completo los [consejos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77616441/mostrar-rango-de-fechas-sql-server) que le dieron sobre el mal uso de las etiquetas en [so].

Comment: Hola Gael, ¿que tipo de dato es la columna `InvTime`? por favor, utiliza la opción [edit] para agregar en tu pregunta la definición de la tabla `View_CNAWFStatus `.

Comment: Si `InvTime` es un `datetime`  prueba filtrar usando el formato ISO: `'2023-12-30 16:00:00'`

Answer (score 0):

Para filtrar los resultados de tu consulta SQL por la columna Invtime y obtener solo aquellos registros que tengan un valor menor o igual a '12/30/2023 4:00 PM', deberías realizar algunos cambios en tu condición WHERE. Además, para asegurarte de que estás comparando fechas correctamente, te recomendaría utilizar el formato estándar de fecha y hora de SQL Server (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS).

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).